# In-Place Radix Sort

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, radix-sort, in-place

This is a long text. Please bear with me. Boiled down, the question is: **Is there a workable in-place radix sort algorithm**?

---

### Preliminary

I've got a huge number of *small fixed-length* strings that only use the letters “A”, “C”, “G” and “T” (yes, you've guessed it: [DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA)) that I want to sort.

At the moment, I use `std::sort` which uses [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) in all common implementations of the [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library). This works quite well. However, I'm convinced that [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) fits my problem set perfectly and should work **much** better in practice.

### Details

I've tested this assumption with a very naive implementation and for relatively small inputs (on the order of 10,000) this was true (well, at least more than twice as fast). However, runtime degrades abysmally when the problem size becomes larger (*N* > 5,000,000).

The reason is obvious: radix sort requires copying the whole data (more than once in my naive implementation, actually). This means that I've put ~ 4 GiB into my main memory which obviously kills performance. Even if it didn't, I can't afford to use this much memory since the problem sizes actually become even larger.

### Use Cases

Ideally, this algorithm should work with any string length between 2 and 100, for DNA as well as DNA5 (which allows an additional wildcard character “N”), or even DNA with [IUPAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry) [ambiguity codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_notation) (resulting in 16 distinct values). However, I realize that all these cases cannot be covered, so I'm happy with any speed improvement I get. The code can decide dynamically which algorithm to dispatch to.

### Research

Unfortunately, the [Wikipedia article on radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is useless. The section about an in-place variant is complete rubbish. The [NIST-DADS section on radix sort](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/radixsort.html) is next to nonexistent. There's a promising-sounding paper called [Efficient Adaptive In-Place Radix Sorting](https://www.mii.vu.lt/informatica/pdf/INFO562.pdf) which describes the algorithm “MSL”. Unfortunately, this paper, too, is disappointing.

In particular, there are the following things.

First, the algorithm contains several mistakes and leaves a lot unexplained. In particular, it doesn’t detail the recursion call (I simply assume that it increments or reduces some pointer to calculate the current shift and mask values). Also, it uses the functions `dest_group` and `dest_address` without giving definitions. I fail to see how to implement these efficiently (that is, in O(1); at least `dest_address` isn’t trivial).

Last but not least, the algorithm achieves in-place-ness by swapping array indices with elements inside the input array. This obviously only works on numerical arrays. I need to use it on strings. Of course, I could just screw strong typing and go ahead assuming that the memory will tolerate my storing an index where it doesn’t belong. But this only works as long as I can squeeze my strings into 32 bits of memory (assuming 32 bit integers). That's only 16 characters (let's ignore for the moment that 16 > log(5,000,000)).

Another paper by one of the authors gives no accurate description at all, but it gives MSL’s runtime as sub-linear which is flat out wrong.

**To recap**: Is there any hope of finding a working reference implementation or at least a good pseudocode/description of a working in-place radix sort that works on DNA strings?

Comment: That is one excellently-written question.

Comment: how small are the small fixed length strings?

Comment: @EvilTeach: I've added the use cases.

Comment: What's the output requirement? Do you want to just produce a sorted list? or are these being put into a database for matching? or...?

Comment: @Jason: I just need the list. Post-processing differs drastically. One use case is actually the creation of a suffix array like lookup table (using k-mers instead of suffixes). The current construction with quicksort beats all usual linear-time methods.

Comment: The question might not be ok. In-place could be as bad as copying if a lot of moves have to be made.

Comment: @Stephan: this is all fine and well. But in the case of copying/cache misses I just get a delay. In the case of memory I hit a phyical limit. This is simply nonnegotiable. All those fancy techniques to store parts of the data on disk are definitely slower than the current quicksort solution.

Comment: (cont') dsimcha's solution, on the other hand, is definitely *faster* than quicksort for some inputs. The number of moves may be high and cache locality small but in the real world, it's still good. I've also tweaked the solution slightly to reduce the number of swaps that I need to perform.

Comment: @PeterMortensen For the future, I appreciate corrections and links to add context. However, I don’t *particularly* appreciate edits that are mere matters of style (“in the order” vs “on the order”, “i.e.” vs “that is”).

Comment: I realize this is an old question but I am interested in what you were trying to do.  I'm teaching a data structures course.  Do you still have a data set to play with?  How big were the strings?  And can you describe what you were sorting the strings for?  It strikes me that what you were then doing with the sorted data is a crucial missing part of this question.  For example, if your purpose was to have a sorted set of sequences that you could then try to splice together, I think potentially building a trie could be a lot faster than sorting the list intact but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Dov That’s a loong time ago but I was working with Illumina next-gen sequencing reads (32 bases) and sorting to build a constant-time lookup index (q-gram index). A trie would of course have been possible but using a q-gram index here has proved to work well in practice (Eland etc.). If I remember correctly the index would then be queried by the GPU – but like I said, it was a long time ago for a project that I’m no longer working on.

Comment: [Algorithm for the fast almost in-place LSD radix sort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93563/fast-stable-almost-in-place-radix-and-merge-sorts)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Well, here's a simple implementation of an MSD radix sort for DNA.  It's written in D because that's the language that I use most and therefore am least likely to make silly mistakes in, but it could easily be translated to some other language.  It's in-place but requires `2 * seq.length` passes through the array.

```cpp
void radixSort(string[] seqs, size_t base = 0) {
    if(seqs.length == 0)
        return;

    size_t TPos = seqs.length, APos = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i < TPos) {
        if(seqs[i][base] == 'A') {
             swap(seqs[i], seqs[APos++]);
             i++;
        }
        else if(seqs[i][base] == 'T') {
            swap(seqs[i], seqs[--TPos]);
        } else i++;
    }

    i = APos;
    size_t CPos = APos;
    while(i < TPos) {
        if(seqs[i][base] == 'C') {
            swap(seqs[i], seqs[CPos++]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(base < seqs[0].length - 1) {
        radixSort(seqs[0..APos], base + 1);
        radixSort(seqs[APos..CPos], base + 1);
        radixSort(seqs[CPos..TPos], base + 1);
        radixSort(seqs[TPos..seqs.length], base + 1);
   }
}
```

Obviously, this is kind of specific to DNA, as opposed to being general, but it should be fast.

## Edit:

I got curious whether this code actually works, so I tested/debugged it while waiting for my own bioinformatics code to run.  The version above now is actually tested and works.  For 10 million sequences of 5 bases each, it's about 3x faster than an optimized introsort.

Comment: If you can live with a 2x pass approach, this extends to radix-N: pass 1 = just go through and count how many there are of each of the N digits. Then if you are partitioning the array this tells you where each digit starts at. Pass 2 does swaps to the appropriate position in the array.

Comment: (e.g. for N=4, if there are 90000 A, 80000 G, 100 C, 100000 T, then make an array initialized to the cumulative sums = [0, 90000, 170000, 170100] which is used in place of your APos, CPos, etc. as a cursor for where the next element for each digit should be swapped to.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the relation between the binary representation and this string representation is going to be, apart from using at least 4 times as much memory as needed

Comment: How is the speed with longer sequences? You don't have enough different ones with a length of 5

Comment: This radix sort looks to be a special case of the American Flag sort - a well known in-place radix sort variant.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but what IDE do you use for D? Been trying to find a nice one...

Comment: CodeBlocks.  It sucks (it's basically just an editor plus basic build automation) and I've been looking for something better, but there are no good IDEs for D2 (the bleeding edge version of the language) yet, and D has enough language level features to eliminate boilerplate code that you don't need a good IDE for it as much as you do for some other languages.

Comment: This code is more akin to a quicksort with a predefined pivot. The proposition from Jason S. seems much simpler to extend to longer prefixes.

Answer (score 21):

I've never seen an in-place radix sort, and from the nature of the radix-sort I doubt that it is much faster than a out of place sort as long as the temporary array fits into memory.

**Reason:**

The sorting does a linear read on the input array, but all writes will be nearly random. From a certain N upwards this boils down to a cache miss per write. This cache miss is what slows down your algorithm. If it's in place or not will not change this effect.

I know that this will not answer your question directly, but if sorting is a bottleneck you may want to have a look at **near sorting** algorithms as a **preprocessing step** (the wiki-page on the soft-heap may get you started).

That could give a very nice cache locality boost. A text-book out-of-place radix sort will then perform better. The writes will still be nearly random but at least they will cluster around the same chunks of memory and as such increase the cache hit ratio.

I have no idea if it works out in practice though.

Btw: If you're dealing with DNA strings only: You can compress a char into two bits and pack your data quite a lot. This will cut down the memory requirement by factor four over a naiive representation. Addressing becomes more complex, but the ALU of your CPU has lots of time to spend during all the cache-misses anyway.

Comment: Two good points; near sorting is a new concept to me, I'll have to read about that. Cache misses is another consideration that haunts my dreams. ;-) I'll have to see about this.

Comment: It's new for me as well (a couple of month), but once you got the concept you start to see performance improvement opportunities.

Comment: The writes are far from _nearly random_ unless your radix is very large. For example, assuming you sort one character at a time (a radix-4 sort) all writes will be to one of 4 linearly growing buckets. This is both cache and prefetch friendly. Of course, you might want to use a larger radix, and at some pointer you hit a tradeoff between cache and prefetch friendliness and radix size. You can push the break-even point towards larger radices using software prefetching or a scratch area for your buckets with periodic flushing to the "real" buckets.

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly drop the memory requirements by encoding the sequence in bits.
You are looking at permutations so, for length 2, with "ACGT" that's 16 states, or 4 bits.
For length 3, that's 64 states, which can be encoded in 6 bits. So it looks like 2 bits for each letter in the sequence, or about 32 bits for 16 characters like you said.

If there is a way to reduce the number of valid 'words', further compression may be possible.

So for sequences of length 3, one could create 64 buckets, maybe sized uint32, or uint64.
Initialize them to zero.
Iterate through your very very large list of 3 char sequences, and encode them as above.
Use this as a subscript, and increment that bucket.
Repeat this until all of your sequences have been processed.

Next, regenerate your list.

Iterate through the 64 buckets in order, for the count found in that bucket, generate that many instances of the sequence represented by that bucket.
when all of the buckets have been iterated, you have your sorted array.

A sequence of 4, adds 2 bits, so there would be 256 buckets.
A sequence of 5, adds 2 bits, so there would be 1024 buckets.

At some point the number of buckets will approach your limits.
If you read the sequences from a file, instead of keeping them in memory, more memory would be available for buckets.

I think this would be faster than doing the sort in situ as the buckets are likely to fit within your working set.

Here is a hack that shows the technique

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const int width = 3;
const int bucketCount = exp(width * log(4)) + 1;
      int *bucket = NULL;

const char charMap[4] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};

void setup
(
    void
)
{
    bucket = new int[bucketCount];
    memset(bucket, '\0', bucketCount * sizeof(bucket[0]));
}

void teardown
(
    void
)
{
    delete[] bucket;
}

void show
(
    int encoded
)
{
    int z;
    int y;
    int j;
    for (z = width - 1; z >= 0; z--)
    {
        int n = 1;
        for (y = 0; y < z; y++)
            n *= 4;

        j = encoded % n;
        encoded -= j;
        encoded /= n;
        cout << charMap[encoded];
        encoded = j;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Sort this sequence
    const char *testSequence = "CAGCCCAAAGGGTTTAGACTTGGTGCGCAGCAGTTAAGATTGTTT";

    size_t testSequenceLength = strlen(testSequence);

    setup();


    // load the sequences into the buckets
    size_t z;
    for (z = 0; z < testSequenceLength; z += width)
    {
        int encoding = 0;

        size_t y;
        for (y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            encoding *= 4;

            switch (*(testSequence + z + y))
            {
                case 'A' : encoding += 0; break;
                case 'C' : encoding += 1; break;
                case 'G' : encoding += 2; break;
                case 'T' : encoding += 3; break;
                default  : abort();
            };
        }

        bucket[encoding]++;
    }

    /* show the sorted sequences */ 
    for (z = 0; z < bucketCount; z++)
    {
        while (bucket[z] > 0)
        {
            show(z);
            bucket[z]--;
        }
    }

    teardown();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why compare when you can hash eh?

Comment: Damn straight.
Performance is generally an issue with any DNA processing.

Answer (score 6):

If your data set is so big, then I would think that a disk-based buffer approach would be best:

```
sort(List<string> elements, int prefix)
    if (elements.Count < THRESHOLD)
         return InMemoryRadixSort(elements, prefix)
    else
         return DiskBackedRadixSort(elements, prefix)

DiskBackedRadixSort(elements, prefix)
    DiskBackedBuffer<string>[] buckets
    foreach (element in elements)
        buckets[element.MSB(prefix)].Add(element);

    List<string> ret
    foreach (bucket in buckets)
        ret.Add(sort(bucket, prefix + 1))

    return ret
```

I would also experiment grouping into a larger number of buckets, for instance, if your string was:

```
GATTACA
```

the first MSB call would return the bucket for GATT (256 total buckets), that way you make fewer branches of the disk based buffer. This may or may not improve performance, so experiment with it.

Comment: We use memory-mapped files for some applications. However, in general we work under the assumption that the machine provides just barely enough RAM to not require explicit disk backing (of course, swapping still takes place). But we are already developing a mechanism for automatic disk-backed arrays

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you switch to a heap/[heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) implementation. This suggestion comes with some assumptions:

1. You control the reading of the data
2. You can do something meaningful with the sorted data as soon as you 'start' getting it sorted.

The beauty of the heap/heap-sort is that you can build the heap while you read the data, and you can start getting results the moment you have built the heap.

Let's step back. If you are so fortunate that you can read the data asynchronously (that is, you can post some kind of read request and be notified when some data is ready), and then you can build a chunk of the heap while you are waiting for the next chunk of data to come in - even from disk. Often, this approach can bury most of the cost of half of your sorting behind the time spent getting the data.

Once you have the data read, the first element is already available. Depending on where you are sending the data, this can be great. If you are sending it to another asynchronous reader, or some parallel 'event' model, or UI, you can send chunks and chunks as you go.

That said - if you have no control over how the data is read, and it is read synchronously, and you have no use for the sorted data until it is entirely written out - ignore all this. :(

See the Wikipedia articles:

- *[Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)*
- *[Binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)*

Comment: Good suggestion. However, I've already tried this and in my particular case the overhead of maintaining a heap is larger than just accumulating the data in a vector and sorting once all the data has arrived.

Answer (score 5):

"[Radix sorting with no extra space](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1778601)" is a paper addressing your problem.

Comment: Looks promising, though the problem has actually already been solved. Still, this goes into my reference library.

Answer (score 4):

Performance-wise you might want to look at a more general string-comparison sorting algorithms.

Currently you wind up touching every element of every string, but you can do better!

In particular, a [burst sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstsort) is a very good fit for this case. As a bonus, since burstsort  is based on tries, it works ridiculously well for the small alphabet sizes used in DNA/RNA, since you don't need to build any sort of ternary search node, hash or other trie node compression scheme into the trie implementation. The tries may be useful for your suffix-array-like final goal as well.

A decent general purpose implementation of burstsort is available on source forge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/burstsort/ - but it is not in-place.

For comparison purposes, The C-burstsort implementation covered at http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/~rsinha/papers/SinhaRingZobel-2006.pdf benchmarks 4-5x faster than quicksort and radix sorts for some typical workloads.

Comment: I'll definitely have to look at burst sort – although at the moment I don't see how the trie could be built in-place. In general suffix arrays have all but replaced suffix trees (and thus, tries) in bioinformatics because of superior performance characteristics in practical applications.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to take a look at [Large-scale Genome Sequence Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1860946356) by Drs. Kasahara and Morishita.

Strings comprised of the four nucleotide letters A, C, G, and T can be specially encoded into Integers for *much* faster processing. Radix sort is among many algorithms discussed in the book; you should be able to adapt the accepted answer to this question and see a big performance improvement.

Comment: The radix sort presented in this book isn’t in-place so it’s not usable for this purpose.  As for the string compaction, I am (of course) already doing this. My (more or less) final solution (posted below) doesn’t show this because the library allows me to treat them like normal strings – but the `RADIX` value used can (and is) of course be adapted to larger values.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  Sorting the data is simply iterating through the dataset and inserting it; the structure is naturally sorted, and you can think of it as similar to a B-Tree (except instead of making comparisons, you *always* use pointer indirections).

Caching behavior will favor all of the internal nodes, so you probably won't improve upon that; but you can fiddle with the branching factor of your trie as well (ensure that every node fits into a single cache line, allocate trie nodes similar to a heap, as a contiguous array that represents a level-order traversal).  Since tries are also digital structures (O(k) insert/find/delete for elements of length k), you should have competitive performance to a radix sort.

Comment: The trie has the same problem as my naive implementation: it requires O(n) additional memory which is simply too much.

Answer (score 3):

I would [burstsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burstsort) a packed-bit representation of the strings. Burstsort is claimed to have much better locality than radix sorts, keeping the extra space usage down with burst tries in place of classical tries. The original paper has measurements.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've solved the problem, but for the record, it appears that one version of a workable in-place radix sort is the "American Flag Sort".  It's described here: [Engineering Radix Sort](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6990).   The general idea is to do 2 passes on each character - first count how many of each you have, so you can subdivide the input array into bins.  Then go through again, swapping each element into the correct bin.   Now recursively sort each bin on the next character position.

Comment: Actually, the solution I use is very closely related to the Flag Sorting algorithm. I don't know if there's any relevant distinction.

Comment: Never heard of the American Flag Sort, but apperently that's what I coded: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94eb75fbecc39066  It's currently outperforming `std::sort`, and I'm certain a multidigit digitizer could go faster still, but my test suite is having memory problems (not the algorithm, the test suite itself)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The big distinction between the Flag sort and other radix sorts is the counting pass.  You're right that all the radix sorts are very closely related, but I wouldn't consider yours a Flag sort.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Just took some inspiration from your sample there - I got stuck in my own independent implementation, and yours helped me get back on track. Thanks! One possible optimization - I haven't gotten far enough here to see if it's worthwhile yet: If the element in the position you are swapping TO happens to already be where it needs to be, you may want to skip that and advance to one that isn't. Detecting this will require extra logic, of course, and possible extra storage as well, but since swaps are expensive relative to compares, it may be worth doing.

Answer (score 2):

Radix-Sort is not cache conscious and is not the fastest sort algorithm for large sets.
You can look at:

- [ti7qsort](http://www.mindspring.com/~pfilandr/C/e_driver/). ti7qsort is the fastest sort for integers (can be used for small-fixed size strings).
- [Inline QSORT](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/qsort.html)
- [String sorting](http://code.google.com/p/string-sorting/)

You can also use compression and encode each letter of your DNA into 2 bits before storing into the sort array.

Comment: bill: could you explain what advantages this `qsort` function has over the `std::sort` function provided by C++? In particular, the latter implements a highly sophisticated introsort in modern libraries and inlines the comparison operation. I don't buy the claim that it performs in O(n) for most cases, since this would require a degree of introspection not available in the general case (at least not without *a lot* of overhead).

Comment: I'm not using c++, but in my tests the inline QSORT can be 3 times faster than the qsort in stdlib. The ti7qsort is the fastest sort for integers (faster than inline QSORT). You can also use it to sort small fixed size data. You must do the tests with your data.

Answer (score 1):

First, think about the coding of your problem. Get rid of the strings, replace them by a binary representation. Use the first byte to indicate length+encoding. Alternatively, use a fixed length representation at a four-byte boundary. Then the radix sort becomes much easier. For a radix sort, the most important thing is to not have exception handling at the hot spot of the inner loop.

OK, I thought a bit more about the 4-nary problem. You want a solution like a [Judy tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array) for this. The next solution can handle variable length strings; for fixed length just remove the length bits, that actually makes it easier.

Allocate blocks of 16 pointers. The least significant bit of the pointers can be reused, as your blocks will always be aligned. You might want a special storage allocator for it (breaking up large storage into smaller blocks). There are a number of different kinds of blocks:

- Encoding with 7 length bits of variable-length strings. As they fill up, you replace them by:
- Position encodes the next two characters, you have 16 pointers to the next blocks, ending with:
- Bitmap encoding of the last three characters of a string.

For each kind of block, you need to store different information in the LSBs. As you have variable length strings you need to store end-of-string too, and the last kind of block can only be used for the longest strings. The 7 length bits should be replaced by less as you get deeper into the structure.

This provides you with a reasonably fast and very memory efficient storage of sorted strings. It will behave somewhat like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). To get this working, make sure to build enough unit tests. You want coverage of all block transitions. You want to start with only the second kind of block.

For even more performance, you might want to add different block types and a larger size of block. If the blocks are always the same size and large enough, you can use even fewer bits for the pointers. With a block size of 16 pointers, you already have a byte free in a 32-bit address space. Take a look at the Judy tree documentation for interesting block types. Basically, you add code and engineering time for a space (and runtime) trade-off

You probably want to start with a 256 wide direct radix for the first four characters. That provides a decent space/time tradeoff. In this implementation, you get much less memory overhead than with a simple trie; it is approximately three times smaller (I haven't measured). O(n) is no problem if the constant is low enough, as you noticed when comparing with the O(n log n) quicksort.

Are you interested in handling doubles? With short sequences, there are going to be. Adapting the blocks to handle counts is tricky, but it can be very space-efficient.

Comment: I don't see how radix sort becomes easier in my case if I use a bit-packed representation. By the way, the framework I use actually provides the possibility of using a bit-packed representation but this is completely transparent for me as a user of the interface.

Comment: Not when you look at your stopwatch :)

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at Judy trees. Vanilla tries don't really bring much to the table though because they behave basically like a normal MSD radix sort with less passes over the elements but require extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

dsimcha's MSB radix sort looks nice, but Nils gets closer to the heart of the problem with the observation that cache locality is what's killing you at large problem sizes.

I suggest a very simple approach:

1. Empirically estimate the largest size `m` for which a radix sort is efficient.
2. Read blocks of `m` elements at a time, radix sort them, and write them out (to a memory buffer if you have enough memory, but otherwise to file), until you exhaust your input.
3. **Mergesort** the resulting sorted blocks.

Mergesort is the most cache-friendly sorting algorithm I'm aware of: "Read the next item from either array A or B, then write an item to the output buffer."  It runs efficiently on *tape drives*.  It does require `2n` space to sort `n` items, but my bet is that the much-improved cache locality you'll see will make that unimportant -- and if you were using a non-in-place radix sort, you needed that extra space anyway.

Please note finally that mergesort can be implemented without recursion, and in fact doing it this way makes clear the true linear memory access pattern.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer perfectly answers the description of the problem, I've reached this place looking in vain for an algorithm to partition inline an array into N parts. I've written one myself, so here it is.

Warning: this is not a stable partitioning algorithm, so for multilevel partitioning, one must repartition each resulting partition instead of the whole array. The advantage is that it is inline.

The way it helps with the question posed is that you can repeatedly partition inline based on a letter of the string, then sort the partitions when they are small enough with the algorithm of your choice.

```
  function partitionInPlace(input, partitionFunction, numPartitions, startIndex=0, endIndex=-1) {
    if (endIndex===-1) endIndex=input.length;
    const starts = Array.from({ length: numPartitions + 1 }, () => 0);
    for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
      const val = input[i];
      const partByte = partitionFunction(val);
      starts[partByte]++;
    }
    let prev = startIndex;
    for (let i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) {
      const p = prev;
      prev += starts[i];
      starts[i] = p;
    }
    const indexes = [...starts];
    starts[numPartitions] = prev;
  
    let bucket = 0;
    while (bucket < numPartitions) {
      const start = starts[bucket];
      const end = starts[bucket + 1];
      if (end - start < 1) {
        bucket++;
        continue;
      }
      let index = indexes[bucket];
      if (index === end) {
        bucket++;
        continue;
      }
  
      let val = input[index];
      let destBucket = partitionFunction(val);
      if (destBucket === bucket) {
        indexes[bucket] = index + 1;
        continue;
      }
  
      let dest;
      do {
        dest = indexes[destBucket] - 1;
        let destVal;
        let destValBucket = destBucket;
        while (destValBucket === destBucket) {
          dest++;
          destVal = input[dest];
          destValBucket = partitionFunction(destVal);
        }
  
        input[dest] = val;
        indexes[destBucket] = dest + 1;
  
        val = destVal;
        destBucket = destValBucket;
      } while (dest !== index)
    }
    return starts;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my response here for those who are still looking for this kind of problems (and where the accepted answer may not do the trick) -

1. It appears that there is an in place radix sort from around this time range - https://duvanenko.tech.blog/2022/04/10/in-place-n-bit-radix-sort/ (latest which in turn has a link to an older paper from around 03-Nov-2009)
2. <s><sub>DNA sequences appear to occur in pairs. 'A' pairs with 'T' or vice-versa I guess and 'G' pairs with 'C' or vice-versa. This reduces the problem to some extent.</sub></s>   DNA pair does not apply here. This is confirmed from [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463105/in-place-radix-sort/77735815?noredirect=1#comment137044780_77735815) in the comments below as well. Considering the sorting problem to be for four characters at a time in a given string (the string length would therefore be a multiple of 4).
3. <s><sub>Given the above, valid permutation would therefore be  'AT CG', 'AT GC', 'TA CG', 'TA GC', 'CG AT', 'CG TA', 'GC AT', 'GC TA'. That makes it 8 combinations over all - assuming we sort in AT/TA/CG/GC pairs.</sub></s>   Given four character permutation, the total number of permutations is 256 (AAAA, AAAT, AAAG, AAAC... and so on) !!
4. <s><sub>This means that we need only eight buckets / bins / counters.</sub></s> Given 256 possibilities, we'd need 256 counters.
5. We make one pass and then increment the corresponding counter that represents one of the   <s><sub>8</sub></s>   256 possibilities.
6. Finally we just print it in order.

Basically we are reducing the problem statement to a kind of counting sort (this approach is also one of the answers above, but in this case I am simply calling it out as counting-sort besides also trying to leverage the fact that the sequences always occur in pairs - which helps manage the problem statement better)

Note: Have also implemented an in-place radix-counting-sort hybrid which I believe is equivalent to the link provided above.

Comment: Unfortunately (2) is an incorrect assumption and therefore the subsequent steps are invalid. — You are misunderstanding how DNA base pairing works. Yes, bases *do* pair (A/T & C/G) but these pairs form between complementary sequences. However, a single, given sequence still has 4 valid letters in any combination, you cannot collapse any of the letters. Put differently, DNA strings are formed from a regular 4-letter alphabet — or, for the purpose of radix sort, DNA sequences are numbers written in 4-ary, i.e. with a radix 4 (the base pairing is simply irrelevant here).

Comment: Yes. Realized that the pair likely only had relevance in the context of double-helix and  not in the context of sequences. However the fact that the sequence size is 4 still helps! This will still limit the combination sufficiently well (24 I guess) for counting sort to work so will update the answer to reflect this point.  Thanks for getting back !

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Can you get back if the above update with 256 counters is the one you were/are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

when there are so little letters, why not just count them?

```
pub fn enum_sort(arr: &mut [Letters]) {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for variant in [Letters::A, Letters::C, Letters::G, Letters::T] {
        map.insert(variant, 0);
    }
    for letter in &mut *arr {
        *map.get_mut(letter).unwrap() += 1;
    }
    let mut index = 0;
    for variant in [Letters::A, Letters::C, Letters::G, Letters::T] {
        let count = map[&variant];
        for _ in 0..count {
            arr[index] = variant;
            index += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I am not sorting letters, I am sorting *strings*. That’s why I need radix sort, not counting sort (which is what your code is implementing).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).