# Time complexity of this algorithm? (Big O)

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of this code, as a part of my assignment. Here is how the code looks like:

```
public int solvePuzzle( )
{
    searchAlg = BINARY_SEARCH ? new BinarySearch() : new LinearSearch();
    int matches = 0;
    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ )
        for( int c = 0; c < columns; c++ )
            for( int rd = -1; rd <= 1; rd++ )
                for( int cd = -1; cd <= 1; cd++ )
                    if( rd != 0 || cd != 0 )
                        matches += solveDirection( r, c, rd, cd );
    searchAlg.printStatistics();
    return matches;
}
```

This method either uses a `Binary Search` or `Linear Search`.

My assignment ask me to find the time complexity of this in `T(M,N) = O(?)` where M is the size of a sorted dictionary which will be search using either linear of binary search, and N is the size of the "puzzle" (char [][]) where both array(Rows and Columns = N = same size).

This part `matches += solveDirection( r, c, rd, cd );` uses either binary/linear search to search through a sorted array.

So far, this is what I've come up with.

The Time complexity of Binary search is `Log M`
The Time complexity of Linear Seach is `M`

The Time complexity of the first two `for-loop`'s are N each.

But what is the Time complexity of the 3rd and 4th loop, and what is `T(M,N)` equal to?

Is it O(3) for the 3r of 4th loop? Does it mean that T(M,N) = O(M * N * N * 3 * 3)/O(logM * N * N * 3 * 3) ?

Any help would de appreciated.

EDIT: the code for `solveDirection()`:

```
private int solveDirection( int baseRow, int baseCol, int rowDelta, int colDelta )
{
    String charSequence = "";
    int numMatches = 0;
    int searchResult;

    charSequence += theBoard[ baseRow ][ baseCol ];

    for( int i = baseRow + rowDelta, j = baseCol + colDelta;
             i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < rows && j < columns;
             i += rowDelta, j += colDelta )
    {
        charSequence += theBoard[ i ][ j ];
        if ( charSequence.length() > maxWordLength )
            break;

        searchResult = searchAlg.search( theWords, charSequence );

        if( searchResult == theWords.length ) {   // corrected by UH 2007-05-02
            // either linear searched failed or binary search failed because charSequence
            // is larger than the largest word in theWords
            if ( searchAlg instanceof BinarySearch )
                break;    // binary search failed and it makes no sense to extend charSequence any further
            else
                continue; // linear search failed but an extension of charSequence may succeed
        }

        // precondition: 0 <= searchResult < theWords.length
        // At this point one, and only one, of three conditions holds:
        // 1. Linear search succeeded
        // 2. Binary search succeded
        // 3. Binary search failed at the insertion point for charSequence, 
        //    which means that theWords[ searchResult ] is the least element greater than charSequence

        if( PREFIX_TESTING && ! theWords[ searchResult ].startsWith( charSequence ) )
            break;

        if( theWords[ searchResult ].equals( charSequence ) ) {
//              if( theWords[ searchResult ].length( ) < 2 )
//                  continue;
            numMatches++;
            if ( PRINT_WORDS ) 
                System.out.println( "Found " + charSequence + " at " +
                        baseRow + " " + baseCol + " to " + i + " " + j );
        }
    }

    return numMatches;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does in solveDirection. Should I add the code for it in my question?

Comment: `O(3)` ? Never heard of such a thing, however `O(1)` means run in constant time. So if you know it's always going to loop 3 times, it would run in constant time.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: @SeanBright Actually nothing, just thought that c++ programmers would understand the code too. Should I remove the tag?

Comment: @ClarkKent Oh ok I see, thanks.

Comment: @CarltonJr. Essentially, your question is not even a Java question since it's not Java specific. Therefore, neither the Java nor the C++ tag fits. That said, that is not really a problem. Anyways, you might want to read the motivation of O-notation, if you do, this might give you some better understanding for what it is good. Then get into why the formal definitions are good to achieve that.

Comment: @Aziuth Okej, will edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track.

However, the key insight is that O(*k*) = O(1) for any constant *k* (= independent of the size of the input). As such, your  O(*N*·*N*·3·3) is the same as O(*N*·*N*). And this result needs to be multiplied with the search, which you’ve done correctly.

Comment: So, does it mean that T(M,N) = O(N^2 * M) and T(M,N) = O(N^2 * log M) ?

Comment: Also, when I tested the code with diffrent sizes of N, a double in N gave either a 4 times or 8 times bigger run time depending on using either binary or linear search

Comment: @CarltonJr. Yes, those are the runtimes. Regarding your test runs, beware that log*M* runtime looks a lot like constant runtime except when many samples are taken, so I’m not surprised that doubling the input size is “only” 4 times slower. See also this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/962545/1968

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the help and the link! Just a quick question, why do you dislike Java? (It said that on your profile, just curious in knowing why)

Comment: @CarltonJr. Because it’s extremely bloated compared to other languages, and requires writing a lot of house-keeping code (as opposed to code that solves actual problems). It also enforces a very bad version of object orientation, and encourages (again, bloated) design patterns. That said, Java 7 has improved this vastly, and Java can be a very productive language.